# Connect PC to phone using proximity

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, wifi-direct

I'm trying to connect a PC to a phone, both running Windows 10 using either UWP's PeerFinder or PeerWatcher. In both cases they can't find each other, though two PCs do.

Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: Unfortunately PeerFinder uses Bluetooth on phones and WiFi on PCs, so they can't see each other. Consider using the Bluetooth RFCOMM APIs instead.

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT Thanks. You can transform your comment into an answer. Is there any plan to change this, it seems like quite a waste?